# SqlCeCommand execution C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create a table pragmatically, my code generates the following syntax:

```
string x = "CREATE TABLE [test] ([ID] int NOT NULL,[Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL"
```

But every time I try to run the code, I generate the following exception.

My code:

```
   SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand(x,conn);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The exception I get:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 66,Token in error  =  NULL ]

I am using `SqlCeConnection` if that makes a difference, and `SqlCeCommand` for execution.

Am I creating the table incorrectly?

My backend connection and execution looks like this :

```
public bool ExecuteSqlCommand(string sqlStr, IList<SqlCeParameter> parameters, SqlCeConnection conn)
{
   SqlCeCommand cmd = null;
   cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

   try
   {
      if (parameters != null)
      {
         foreach (SqlCeParameter param in parameters)
         {
             cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
         }
      }

      cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;

      int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      bool DDLCommand = sqlStr.StartsWith("Drop ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
      DDLCommand = DDLCommand || sqlStr.StartsWith("Delete ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
      DDLCommand = DDLCommand || sqlStr.StartsWith("Insert ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
      DDLCommand = DDLCommand || sqlStr.StartsWith("Update ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
      DDLCommand = DDLCommand || sqlStr.StartsWith("Create ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
      DDLCommand = DDLCommand || sqlStr.StartsWith("Alter ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

      if (DDLCommand || affectedRows > 0)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       SqlCeException sqlEx = e as SqlCeException;
   }

   if (cmd != null)
       cmd.Dispose();

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you opened the connection?

Comment: If you run the command directly against the DB (e.g. in SQL Server Management Studio), does it work? You appear to be missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: It seems that ")" is missing at the end of the SQL query (string x): string x = "CREATE TABLE [test] ([ID] int NOT NULL,[Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)"; // <- ")"

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `SqlCeCommand`, then?  A good practice is to just use `connection.CreateCommand()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not closing your `(`

```
string x = "CREATE TABLE [test] ([ID] int NOT NULL,[Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)"
```

Answer (score 5):

Your query is missing `)`

```
"CREATE TABLE [test] ([ID] int NOT NULL,[Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)"
```